# Missing commits after creating files via GitHub website

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I was adding some new files to my fork of a rather large repo. However, due to some issues I was having with git I had to add the files via the GitHub website. The repo owner has asked that I squash my 5 commits into one. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to do this via the GitHub website so I got on another computer and pull in the code from my fork. I tried to do this via `git rebase`; however, my commits are not showing up in the log. Why is this? Did I forget to do something when I pull in the code?

Comment: did you checkout the intended branch? By default it is master.  (Sorry if this is a rhetorical question :D )

Comment: I was working in the master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have been working on a branch and have asked for a pull request on this branch and now even master has those commits.

But you can do the following:

`git checkout master`

`git reset --soft COMMIT_NUMBER_BEFORE_YOU_STARTED_TO_WORK`

- this won't affect your working directory
- this will only rewind the HEAD at the time when you started
- this way when you'll `git status` you'll see all the modifications you did

`git status`

- make sure those are your modifications

`git checkout -b feature/my-feature`

- switch branch (we won't commit on master)

If there were untracked (there shouldn't be) : `git add .`

`git commit -m "all modifications in one commit"`

- that way you provide all modifications in one commit as asked by the maintainer
- AND this is not on `master` (much better)

`git push -u origin feature/my-feature`

- you push the branch with your commit to your remote repo
- finally, you ask for a pull-request on this branch `feature/my-feature`

The merge will be done by the maintainer by accepting the pull-request. After, you'll have to retrieve that merge and inject it to your master branch (this is for later) - see how to get in sync with a fork on Github.